# How to make an update for android app from completely new app

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an app from the scratch, but customer wan to make it as an update for the existing app on the play store. How can I do it, and what do I need (certificates, key stores etc.) ?

Comment: Yes you need the keystore of the application

Comment: I believe that the new app will have to have the same package name, the version code will need to be higher. If you have the keystore then sign the new app with it as well. If you don't have the key then the users will have to uninstall the old app first, which will wipe all of their local data and preferences

Answer (score 3):

There are mainly few things that you need to keep in mind while you are going to create an update for an app.

**1.The package name of the app should be the same**

-This will make sure there is only 1 instance of this app running in the device, the app is recognized as another version of the app developed.

**2.You will need the keystore file which is used during the release of the previous version.**

-This is to make sure the digital signature remains the same for this update too.
**

**3.Version number in the manifest file of the app.**

**
-You have to increase the app version in the manifest file without fail for the android system to identify this app as a new version of that app.
change the value of "android:versionName" & "android:versionCode" in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the old code of your project and modify it first and if you don't have source of your old app then make sure that the package name of your new app is match with old app and version of your current app is also higher then previous app other wise it's not possible to update in Google play.

Right click on your project and click on Export tab then select Android then select Export Android Application then Browse your project (I think it's by default same so no need to do anything just click next),

Now select Use Existing keystore (By default selected) and browse your **Keystorefile** as well as password which you enter last time then click Next.

Create alias and again enter the same password then give APK name with .apk extension and then click on finish.

After doing this all step if you are getting error anywhere then might be your password or your keyfile is wrong.

**PS:** Don't forget to update your app version in manifest file